# In a standard deck of 52 cards, how many different 7 card hands are there in which 3 cards are hearts and the other 4 are of different suits?

Tags: probability, statistics, permutations

I know there are 13 cards in each suit, so that would mean I needed 3 of the 13 hearts or 13 P 3, then the other 4 would need to be out of 39 so it would be 39 P 4 but I don't know where to go from here...

Comment: You are on the right track, except that instead of permutations (order is important) my reading of the question is that we are only interested in combinations. Thereafter we proceed to multiply the two numbers because of the principle of counting (you require both actions to be simultaneous).

Comment: Correct.  If I'm not mistaken, this means your answer would be:

$$\frac{{13 \choose 3}{39 \choose 4}}{52 \choose 7}≈.175833$$

Comment: @NathanTowle the problem is that that doesn't make sense as to how many different 7 card hands there are with 3 hearts and 4 different suits. That is the probability that I'll get one, but not the number of hands I can achieve....

Comment: It's just the nominator.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe so it would be 23523786?

Comment: @FiguringItOut yes, you are correct. I misread the question.  Thanks for catching that!

Comment: @NathanTowle thank you for answering! Did I get the correct answer then? 23523786??

Comment: @Michael: I think that you mean the *numerator*.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott yes that's what he meant... Can anyone tell me if I got it right........ lol.

Comment: @FiguringItOut: You mean $23,523,786$? Yes, that’s correct.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott THANKS!!!!!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks, Brian, it's just to early now here in Germany.

Comment: If you guys are interested I have a probability question for you lol

Comment: @Michael: No problem. I’m just surprised that you used it for *numerator*: I’d have expected it to match up better with *Nenner* than with *Zähler*.

Answer (score 2):

In this case Since its not asking you in how many ways can it be ordered to be dealt 3 hearts and 4 other suites the question is asking about Combinations. 
There are 52 cards in a deck. There are 4 suites in a deck. so 52/4 = 13 cards of each suite.

So we need to CHOOSE 3 cards with a heart suite out of the 13 cards with a heart suite availiable to us. That is just 13 C 4. So for the cards that are not hearts we have 
52-13 = 39. So we need any 4 of those that are not hearts so its just 39 C 13. The total number of ways to pick any 7 cards is 52 C 7.

These types of problems can be tricky in figuring out wheter or not its a permuation or combination problem. If they don't specify order you have to be able to realise that it's a combination problem.

In this case let's say
Probability = (# of ways to get 3 hearts) x (# of ways to get 4 other card) / (Possible # of ways to choose 7 cards

so we have :
(13 C 3) x ( 39 C 4 ) / (52 C 7)
hope this helps!